# Why did Alan name the baby Carlos?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hangover

In [The Hangover](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1119646/) movie, why did Alan name the baby **Carlos**?

The conversation in the elevator:

> Woman: What’s his name?
>   Phil: Ben
>   Alan: Carlos
>   Phil and Stu: Carlos?

After seeing the baby's mom:

> Alan: Did you hear that? Baby's name is Tyler
>   Phil: Yeah. I thought he looked more like a Carlos too, bud

I'm not a native speaker, is there any fun behind the name Carlos? Or was there some other reason Alan chose the name Carlos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's a random joke, likely due to the fact the baby is white and the name is typically Hispanic**.

Alan's whole character in the film is very, *very* random. They find a baby and wonder whose it is. Although Phil suggests Ben, Alan quickly says Carlos and takes to calling the baby that.

Finally, later the gang discover the baby's name is Tyler. Phil acknowledges he hears this and simply remarks he thought the kid looked more like a Carlos.

The baby isn't mentioned again and doesn't appear in *Hangover 2* (although will be back, all grown up, in *Hangover 3*).

There is no deep joke here. Carlos is a Spanish name and in the US would be more typical of a Hispanic child, as opposed to a white child. Calling the baby Carlos is just another unusual quirk of Alan's.